# Запрос mysql_query не работает

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте!

Постоянно путаюсь в синтаксисе

Скажите - правильно ли составлен запрос на внесение в БД?

```
$add_true_ads = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `samara_rent` (date_create, type, address, description, furniture, repair, price, phone) VALUES ('30.01.2014', '".$row['rooms']."', '".$row['address']."', '".$row['description']."', '".$row['furniture']."', '".$row['repair']."', '".$row['price']."', '".$row['phone']."')", $db_fyes);
```

Если нет - исправите. Напишите верный

Спасибо!

Comment: внешне похоже на правильное, если не вдаваться в подробности структуры таблицы.  
а что, не работает? а проверить?

Comment: '30.01.2014' -- дата неправильного формата, но MySQL не должен считать это за ошибку. А вообще print mysql_error($db_fyes);

Comment: а если поле date_create varchar или text? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте после запроса такие строки:

```
echo mysql_errno($db_fyes) . ": " . mysql_error($db_fyes). "\n";
```

В них будет содержаться данные об ошибке.

Answer (score -1):

Зайдите в PHPMyAdmin создайте новую запись в таблицу и скопируйте полученный итоговый результат.